# Sparql and Pandas conversion in Wikidata

Tags: python, pandas, sparql, wikidata

1. I have queried Wikidata [https://query.wikidata.org/] via sparqlwrapper in python.
2. It returns as an XML for some reason instead of CSV.
   [Result of query in python](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vIaSs.png)
3. I convert it to a Pandas DataFrame in python.

Question:

I am new to pandas, which method should I use to convert it into a format where every row is a wikidata entity, and every column is a possible feature? Also, is there a way to do it as fast as possible using numpy?

Need to convert from :
[Image of SPARQL Query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VAXhb.png)
to
([Image of optimal format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wYZIy.png))

Thank you.

Query used below:

```
    SELECT DISTINCT ?company ?companyLabel ?description ?wdLabel ?ps_Label

    {
    VALUES ?company {wd:Q396266 wd:Q3270129 wd:Q359194 wd:P3562 wd:Q119230}

    ?company ?p ?statement .
    ?statement ?ps ?ps_ .
    ?company schema:description ?description.
      
    ?wd wikibase:claim ?p.
    ?wd wikibase:statementProperty ?ps.
    OPTIONAL {
    ?statement ?pq ?pq_ .
    ?wdpq wikibase:qualifier ?pq .
    }
        FILTER ( lang(?description) = "en" )

    SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "en" .
                            
    }
    } ORDER BY ?wd ?statement ?ps_
```

Should I use pd.pivot_table or melt etc?

Comment: what means "I convert it to CSV"? SPARQL allows for CSV as resultset already, no need to convert from XML or JSON first. The rest is just loading the CSV into a Pandas dataframe - in fact each column exactly reflects one variable in your `SELECT` projection part

Comment: Would you be open to trying to do the whole thing in SPARQL?

Comment: "It returns as an XML for some reason instead of CSV." -> that is a possible response format and the default format aksed by sparqlwrapper. You can request any other valid SPARQL response format as well: `setReturnFormat(SPARQLWrapper.CSV)`

Comment: Hi @UninformedUser, I apologize. I meant that I converted it to a dataframe in python. I am unable to get it in CSV format via sparqlwrapper. It only sent back either JSON or XML . I chose JSON and then I created a DataFrame with it.

Comment: Hi @HES, sure, essentially i just want every row representing an entity and all of its properties.

Comment: see my last comment, use CSV as return format and you're done

Comment: Hi @UninformedUser, thank you for your reply but after setting setReturnFormat(CSV), it still returns XML. Nevertheless, I just want to know which pandas methods would be useful for converting the dataframe into the optimal format. Groupby/Melt/Pivot..I'm not sure

Comment: then just use https://github.com/lawlesst/sparql-dataframe - don'T reinvent the wheel

Comment: that snippet definitely returns CSV: `from SPARQLWrapper import SPARQLWrapper, CSV, SELECT, POST, POSTDIRECTLY

sparql = SPARQLWrapper(
    "https://query.wikidata.org/sparql"
)
sparql.setReturnFormat(CSV)
sparql.setOnlyConneg(True)
sparql.addCustomHttpHeader("Content-type", "application/sparql-query")
sparql.addCustomHttpHeader("Accept", "text/csv")
sparql.setMethod(POST)
sparql.setRequestMethod(POSTDIRECTLY)`